# CMake ExternalProject_Add() that uses a parent folder in its include_directories()

Tags: cmake, external-project

I have an 'int_tester' CMake project that makes use of `ExternalProject_Add` for its 'drv' dependency. Now, this 'drv' is also built using CMake, and it uses a parent directory in its include_directories(). Trouble is that I do not know how to copy this parent folder inside `ExternalProject_Add()`.

Directory structure is like:

```
/  
|-common  
|-IP  
| |-int_tester  
| |-drv
```

CMakeLists.txt for drv looks like:

```
add_library(SPT_driver STATIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c)  
target_include_directories(SPT_driver
    PUBLIC  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/api/
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../common/include/
)
```

CMakeLists.txt for int_tester like:

```
add_executable(int_tester ...)  
ExternalProject_Add(drv_ext
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/drv/drv_dir
    URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../drv
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
add_library(drv_import STATIC IMPORTED) #phony lib
add_dependencies (drv_import drv_ext) #link phony lib to the external proj
ExternalProject_Get_Property(drv_ext install_dir) #find out where the external proj is installed
set_property(TARGET drv_import PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${install_dir}/src/drv_ext-build/obj/drv.a) #so that the phony lib can have a target
include_directories(${install_dir}/src/drv_ext/api) #and to make current executable dependent on api .h and .a of the externally built lib
target_link_libraries(int_tester drv_import)
```

As one can see, drv depends on `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../common/include/`.

When 'int_tester' builds 'drv' (via `ExternalProject_Add`), folder `../../common/include/` cannot be found (it is not brought it by `ExternalProject_Add`). Even if I add another fake ExternProject for this common folder, its directory structure will not match the one expected by `CMakeLists.txt` of 'drv'.

What am I missing, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build 'drv' using `IP/drv` as its *source directory*, explicitely specify *SOURCE_DIR* option for `ExternalProject_Add`:

```
ExternalProject_Add(drv_ext
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/drv/drv_dir
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../drv
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

Without this option, source directory is deduced from *PREFX* (see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html) for exact algorithm of that deduction).

---

Option *URL* for `ExternalProject_Add` denotes directory, which should be **copied** into the source one. If you do not want to copy, do not use that option.

Comment: Thank you, I understand! Then, in order to properly depend on the api .h files of drv, I should replace include_directories(${install_dir}/src/drv_ext/api) - which no longer works, as .h/.c files are no longer copied into install_dir - with [target_] include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../drv/api), right?

Comment: Did `install_dir` work anyway? You have installation step disabled (via *INSTALL_COMMAND* set to empty string), so nothing should be installed. As for `include_directories`, if `drv` project provides them in its source dir, you may point to that directory, right.